# pyMongo connection with MongoDB Atlas is showing ServerSelectionTimeoutError

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@resume.vrpe7.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.get_database('resumeDB')

job = db.job #code works upto here

job.count_documents({})
```

The code works up to *job = db.job* but the code keeps loading in the last line and finally shows the following error.

ServerSelectionTimeoutError: resume-shard-00-01.vrpe7.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed,resume-shard-00-02.vrpe7.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed,resume-shard-00-00.vrpe7.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 62108e85845eec7528b1dde9, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('resume-shard-00-00.vrpe7.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('resume-shard-00-00.vrpe7.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('resume-shard-00-01.vrpe7.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('resume-shard-00-01.vrpe7.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('resume-shard-00-02.vrpe7.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('resume-shard-00-02.vrpe7.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>]>

Answer (score 1):

Pymongo doesn't make a connection to the database until the first database call. That's why your initial code looks like it is working fine.

The reasons for a `ServerSelectionTimeoutError` are many (there's plenty of examples on this site), but with Atlas it's most likely that You can't reach the Atlas server due to network reasons, and the most likely reason for that is you haven't opened the firewall on the Atlas site to connect from wherever your code is running.